# ArrayList adding incorrect values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to add arrays to an `ArrayList` to check whether they have been seen before. When I add one array to the list, I want to add all other "cycled" versions of the same array to the list also. However when I try changing the values of the array and then adding to the list (code below) the `ArrayList` just fills up with copies of the original array.

```
for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
  int temp = values[0];
  for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
    values[j] = values[j + 1];
  }
  values[11] = temp;
  seen.add(values);
}
```

Comment: copy the values into new arrays.

Comment: Sheesh tough crowd. That worked, but I don't understand why I needed to do that.

Comment: If you don't make a new array, you are adding references the same array in the list (so they all have the same values).

Comment: Ahhh interesting. Guess it's just a way for ArrayList to save some time then? The first array gets cached so every time we add it the same array just gets reused?

Comment: It isn't caching.  The ArrayList holds references to the objects in it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a single array variable, `values`, that you modify in each iteration of the loop. When you add an object to an (Array)List, it isn't copied - a reference to it is just stored in the list. So when you continue modifying **the same object**, there changes will also be visible when accessing the object from the list.

Instead, you should create a new array on each iteration of the loop, and add different objects to the list:

```java
for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
  int[] temp = new int[12];
  for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
    temp[j] = values[(j + 1) % 12];
  }
  seen.add(temp);
}
```